# Deriving an Analytical Expression for Standard Deviation of Log Returns

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, itos-lemma, log-returns, standard-deviation

I am looking to find an expression for the standard deviation log returns of a stock price process.

I have a stock price which follows the following dynamics:

- $dY(t) = Y(t)(r(t)dt + η(t)dW(t))$

Here, W (t) is a two–dimensional vector–valued Brownian motion with independent components and η(t) is a two–dimensional (time-dependent) vectors. With:

- $\eta(t)$ = $ξ(t)$ $ \begin{bmatrix}η_{1}\\η_{2}\end{bmatrix} $
- $\eta_1^2 + \eta_2^2 = 1$

How would I find an expression for log returns, which is defined:

$\sqrt{(Var[\log{}Y(t + ∆t) − \log{} Y (t)|F_t])}$

I believe you can use Ito's lemma we can get the solution to the above SDE:

- $Y(t) = Y(0)\exp(r(t) - \frac{1}{2} η(t)^2)t + η(t)W(t))$

Is the above done correctly? Considering the drift and volatility both depend on a time component

If so, or otherwise, what is the next steps to find an expression for the standard deviation of log returns

Any helps/tips is highly appreciated

Comment: Pls consider learning a bit of LaTeX or using an online editor so that your equations are easier to read.

Comment: Noted. Question has been edited to make it easier to read. Please let me know if any other adjustments need to be made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You solution formula in the question is not correct, it should be
$$Y(t) = Y(0)\cdot \exp\left(\int_0^t\left(r(s)-\frac{1}{2}\eta^T(s)\cdot \mathbf{W}(s)  \right)dt +\int_0^t\ \eta^T(s)d\mathbf{W}(s)   \right) $$
where $^T$ is the transpose of a vector.

For the log return formula, you have
$$\begin{align}
R&:=\sqrt{V(\ln Y(t + ∆t) − \ln Y (t)|\mathcal{F}_t)}\\
&=\sqrt{V\left(\underbrace{\int_t^{t+\Delta t}\left(r(s)-\frac{1}{2}\eta^T(s)\cdot \mathbf{W}(s)  \right)dt}_{\text{constant term, don't affect the variance, so ignore}} +\int_t^{t+\Delta t}\ \eta^T(s)d\mathbf{W}(s)\right)}\\
&=\sqrt{V\left(\underbrace{\int_t^{t+\Delta t}\ \eta^T(s)dW(s)}_{\text{expectation is equal to }0}\right)}\\
&=\sqrt{\underbrace{\mathbb{E}\left(\left(\int_t^{t+\Delta t}\ \eta^T(s)d\mathbf{W}(s)\right)^2\right)}_{\text{Ito isometry }}}\\
R&=\color{red}{\sqrt{\int_t^{t+\Delta t}\ \left(\eta^T(s)\cdot \eta(s) \right)ds}}\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: @user67245 yes, with this condition, the result can be simplified to the formula you wrote.